# Seeking outline/boundary (shapefile) of Ganges river basin?

Tags: data, india, basin, bangladesh

I'm looking for an outline/boundary (shapefile) of the Ganges river basin.

Where can I find this?

Comment: I think this is a question that would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The Global River Basins data at the [WaterBase](http://www.waterbase.org/download_data.html#id10) site looks like it might be useful. The big downside I see is that the shapefile only has codes, no names. However, it seems to align decently with the [Watershed Atlas of India](http://cgwb.gov.in/watershed/index.html) maps found at the Central Ground Water Board, so at worst maybe you could cross-reference that way.

Alternatively, if you have a connection to Stanford University, they have [Indian river basin data](https://earthworks.stanford.edu/?q=rivers%20india&utf8=%E2%9C%93), but it is restricted to "current faculty, staff, and students."